# Accidentally deleted package.json, is there anyway for you to regenerate it?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I had a JSON error in my package and by accident deleted it. Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: weren't you using any VCS like git?

Comment: Git? Your IDE local cache? Your trash? `npm init` and start from scratch?

Comment: was it create-react-app? if yest then just generate one more blank project and take package.json. At least this will solve half of problem then you can install other stuff?

Comment: thanks Indrajeet, this was a really stupid question sorry guys I'm such a noob at this

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are not using git or similar systems the last thing you can do is to use software like Recuva to restore a deleted file.

Comment: Try to use npm init -y . this worked for me

Comment: @mithunSalinda This doesn't restore the packages to package.json that may be installed in node_modules, or present in a package-lock.json, just generates a generic package.json file.